# Substring a part of a string using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a string like this `string(1)`, I want to get substring remove the last part to obtain just `string` any suggestions please!!

PS.the string could be: `sringggg(125)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use various options to get the desired string.

```js
//With regular expression with split() and fetch the first element of array
console.log('sringggg(125)'.split(/\(\d+\)/)[0]);

//Using string with split() and fetch the first element of array
console.log('sringggg(125)'.split('(')[0]);

//Using substr and indexOf
var str = 'sringggg(125)'
console.log(str.substr(0, str.indexOf('(')));
```

References

- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

If string is always in same pattern and ' ( ' is a separator  use split .

```
var string =  'string(1)'
var result = string .split('(')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regexp

```
var tesst = "string(1)"
var test = tesst.match(/^[^\(]+/);
// test = "string"
```